# Inductor Charging and Discharging

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, experimental-physics

Why does the inductor discharges in the same path ( same direction of current ) as that of its charging unlike a capacitor which discharges in the direction opposite to its charging(current direction is reversed in discharging).? 
What could be its physical reason (for Lenz's Law)

Answer (score 2):

For a capacitor, the voltage across must be continuous since the current through since

$$i_C = C \frac{dv_C}{dt}$$

Since the current through is proportional to the time derivative of the voltage across, the $v_C(t)$ must be differentiable, i.e., there can be no discontinuous change.

There is no such limitation on the capacitor current, the direction and/or magnitude can be discontinuous.

The inductor is the electrical *dual* to the capacitor so we have

$$v_L = L \frac{di_L}{dt}$$

and thus, the inductor current must be continuous and so, *the current cannot discontinuously change*.  Instead, the *slope* of the current changes discontinuously from increasing (the inductor is 'charging') to decreasing (the inductor is 'discharging') and the voltage across instantaneously changes sign and possibly magnitude.

The physical reason is [Faraday's law of induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Qualitative_statement).  Since the magnetic flux threading the inductor is proportional to the inductor current, an abrupt change in current implies an abrupt change in magnetic flux which, by Faraday's law *implies an 'infinite' (arbitrarily large) emf*.

Answer (score 0):

When the current stops, the magnetic field inside a conducting loop diminishes, this produces an Electromotive force ($\nabla \times E=-\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$). This force can be looked as "resisting" the changing magnetic flux field and producing a current to counter it.

Answer (score 0):

You asked "Inductors discharge in the same direction unlike Capacitors which discharge in the opposite directions. Why?".
Because Capacitors ARE unlike Inductors.

Think of capacitors as pseudo-voltage sources and Inductors as pseudo-current sources. Both of which, the circuit has to charge.

Capacitor accrues in voltage difference from the circuit. Whereas, the inductor accrues the current. Because of the acquired voltage difference, it produces effective current in opposite direction. Whereas inductor in operation stays in the same direction.